# Getting started with Fabric8, AWS using stackpoint

Tags: fabric8

I have historically used a lot of manual chaining to get a CI pipeline in place for microservice development so am excited to try Fabric8 as it seems that it will make life a lot easier. Running into some early issues though.

I did manage to get Fabric8 running locally but want to get things running on AWS so I can present a more real world flow to stakeholders. Following the notes on this page [Fabric8 on AWS](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/aws.html#install-the-fabric8-microservices-platform) I was able to get a 3 server cluster running using Stackpoint. But, I cannot connect to that cluster to be able to start administering the services. The page references this link (http://fabric8.default.replace.me.io) but it is not working for me. Tried hitting each of the AWS instances by public IP but that failed also. What would be my next steps here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah the getting started guides don't really explain this in great deal.  There's a similar issue on the fabric8 issue tracker that we've tried to help answer  [how to access the console](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/issues/95#issuecomment-242645321)

TL;DR using the AWS loadbalancer can add expense so we deploy an NGINX reverse proxy so you can set up a wildcard DNS.  We use and recommend [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for that as its free for this type of use and fast to setup.

We also created a blog to explain the different options [how to access apps on kubernetes](https://blog.fabric8.io/accessing-your-applications-on-kubernetes-or-openshift-3e69be0ad3bc)

Hope that helps!

Comment: The wildcard dns domain that you configure in cloudflare (or another provider) can then be passed as a flag when deploying fabirc8 i.e. `gofabric8 deploy --domain aws.fabric8.io`, you would then be able to access the fabric8 console at `http://fabirc8.aws.fabirc8.io`

Comment: So in my case and assuming I have a domain creative.io available. I am going to create an A name record for aws.creative.io and a cname of *.aws which resolves to aws.creative.io. What if I already just followed the cookbook and did    gofabric8 deploy --domain replace.me.io   how do I change whats on the pods or etch-a-sketch and do over?

Comment: FWIW we're going add the option to avoid setting up the wildcard dns and use the GKE / AWS loadbalancers instead so things just work OOTB for folks wanting a quick way to get up and running.  Hopefully this will be released at the start of next week.

Comment: If you want to recreate the ingress rules after re running gofabric8 deploy as you did with `gofabric8 deploy --domain aws.creative.io` then you can delete the existing ingress rules and bounce the exposecontroller pod.  `kubectl delete ing --all && kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods | grep exposecontroller | cut -f 1 -d ' ') && kubectl get ing -w` - I've just tested that command and it worked fine here so hopefully that helps.

Comment: I came across this great video which really helped but did lead me to another problem. Will post a new question on SO to avoid muddying this one. Thanks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNRpGJTSMKA